# compiling c++ code using gnu/c getline() on mac osx?

Tags: c++, macos, g++, gnu, incompatibility

I'm trying to compile a pre-existing c++ package on my mac osx leopard machine, and get the following error:

```
    error: no matching function for call to 'getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*&)'
```

This is probably because getline() is a GNU specific extension.

Can I somehow make the osx default g++ compiler recognize such GNU specific extensions?

(if not, I could always supply my own implementation or GNUs original one, but I prefer to have a "cleaner" solution if possible)

Answer (score 5):

`getline` is defined in `stdio.h` in glibc version 2.10 and later, but not in earlier versions, nor (so far; **added** 10.5 definitely didn't have `getline`, and 10.7 definitely does) in the BSD derived libc.

The change in the GNU libraries came about because of a change in the POSIX 2008 standard, which now includes `getline`.

Presumably, this will propogate to other libc over time. In the mean time, I understand that it is causing trouble for a lot of projects.

You can [download a stand alone version from GNU](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735126/are-there-alternate-implementations-of-gnu-getline-interface).

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the solution is to use `autoconf` or some similar tool to determine whether the current platform already has `getline` or not, and supply your own definition only when needed.

Example:

```
# configure.ac
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([getline])

// compat.h
#include "config.h"
#ifndef HAVE_GETLINE
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
#endif

// getline.c
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream) {
    /* definition */
}

# Makefile.am
program_LDADD = $(if $(HAVE_GETLINE),,getline.o)
```

or something along those lines, you'll have to adjust it to match your own program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've ever seen that specific definition of 'getline' here is the one I know of which uses c++ streams+strings.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/