# strdup error on g++ with c++0x

Tags: gcc, c++11, g++, compiler-errors, strdup

I have some C++0x code. I was able to reproduce it below. The code below works fine without `-std=c++0x` however i need it for my real code.

How do i include strdup in C++0x? with gcc 4.5.2

note i am using mingw. i tried including cstdlib, cstring, string.h and tried using std::. No luck.

```
>g++ -std=c++0x a.cpp
a.cpp: In function 'int main()':
a.cpp:4:11: error: 'strdup' was not declared in this scope
```

code:

```
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    strdup("");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works on gcc 4.5.1. Try `#include `<cstring>` and using `std::strdup`, that's the "C++ way". (Still isn't an answer, though, since that should be valid too, IIRC.)

Comment: @GMan: I modified my question. I tried it and no luck :(. As a temp solution i put extern C `_CRTIMP char* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW strdup (const char*) __MINGW_ATTRIB_MALLOC; ` in my headers. It works with that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

-std=gnu++0x (instead of -std=c++0x) does the trick for me; -D_GNU_SOURCE didn't work (I tried with a cross-compiler, but perhaps it works with other kinds of g++).

It appears that the default (no -std=... passed) is "GNU C++" and not "strict standard C++", so the flag for "don't change anything except for upgrading to C++11" is -std=gnu++0x, not -std=c++0x; the latter means "upgrade to C++11 and be stricter than by default".

Answer (score 9):

`strdup` may not be included in the library you are linking against (you mentioned mingw). I'm not sure if it's in c++0x or not; I know it's not in earlier versions of C/C++ standards.

It's a very simple function, and you could just include it in your program (though it's not legal to call it simply "strdup" since all names beginning with "str" and a lowercase letter are reserved for implementation extensions.)

```
char *my_strdup(const char *str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *x = (char *)malloc(len+1); /* 1 for the null terminator */
    if(!x) return NULL; /* malloc could not allocate memory */
    memcpy(x,str,len+1); /* copy the string into the new buffer */
    return x;
}
```

Comment: its reserved yet its nonstandard!?

Comment: `malloc` may need a cast to `char *` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099669/invalid-conversion-from-void-to-char-when-using-malloc)

Comment: @Steve That's what I get for coding it as C because it's normally a C function. Yes, it needs a cast in C++.

Comment: `strdup` not in ANSI C, `#define` feature test macro may not be the best choice, some other `strdup-like` may need other feature test (`_GNU_SOURCE`, `_BSD_SOURCE`, ...). Just implement it.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) explains that strdup is conforming, among others, to the POSIX and BSD standards, and that GNU extensions implement it. Maybe if you compile your code with "-D_GNU_SOURCE" it works?

**EDIT**: just to expand a bit, you probably do not need anything else than including cstring on a POSIX system. But you are using GCC on Windows, which is not POSIX, so you need the extra definition to enable strdup.

Answer (score 0):

add this preprocessor "_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE" to Project Properties->C/C++ Build->GCC C++ Compiler->Preprocessor->Tool Settings

Don't forget to check Preprocessor Only(-E)

This worked for me on windows mingw32.

Comment: That's an MSVC flag.