# "Invalid conversion" error when using malloc?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [invalid conversion from `void*&#39; to` char*' when using malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099669/invalid-conversion-from-void-to-char-when-using-malloc)

I'm trying to allocate a matrix dinamically on the memmory using pointers, but I keep receiving the error messages:

> |122|error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int**'|
>
> |124|error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*'|

Here is my code, I can't see what I'm doing wrong... this "void*" conversion does not make sense for me...

```
   int i,j;
   int **a;
   int c = 2;
 

   /* Form the matrix */
   a = malloc((nxy+1)*sizeof(int *));
   for (i=0;i<=nxy;i++)
      a[i] = malloc((nxy+1)*sizeof(int));
   
   for (i=0;i<=nxy;i++)
      for (j=0;j<=nxy;j++)
         a[i][j] = 0;
```

Comment: Are you definitely compiling with a C compiler and not a C++ compiler?

Comment: Adding to @CharlesBailey comment. Are you compiling this in a .cpp file in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm actually using Code::Blocks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are compiling your program with a C++ compiler.  You have two choices:

1. Don't do that.  Use a C compiler.
2. Cast the return value from `malloc()`.

Comment: What do you mean? How should I cast the return value if it is just a portion of NULL memmory?

Comment: `a = (int **)malloc(....)`.  I don't understand your question.

Comment: Nevermind, I was just making a mess on my head lol, I got it now