# avoiding malloc in c++ : invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘uv_loop_t*

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, smart-pointers, libuv

I'm trying to learn libuv by creating small programs with help of it's documentation. Note that I'll be using it via `c++` language and not `c`. Here's what I started out with -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <uv.h>

int main() {
    uv_loop_t *loop = malloc(sizeof(uv_loop_t));
    uv_loop_init(loop);

    std::cout << "Running loop" << std::endl;
    uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

    uv_loop_close(loop);
    free(loop);
    return 0;
}
```

and compiled it with - `g++ -std=c++14 -luv main.cpp` which should give `a.out` as output file, but it fails with an error -

> invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘uv_loop_t* {aka uv_loop_s*}

which is pointing to malloc usage. I confirmed it by replacing those lines with old libuv way to do this -

```
uv_loop_t* loop = uv_loop_new();
...
uv_loop_delete(loop);
```

which shouldn't work but surprisingly works and compiles fine here.

But I think instead of dodging around this problem, I should solve this with a good way in c++. So here I'm asking for a good alternative in c++ (probably without malloc/manual memory management) so I can proceed further.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [invalid conversion from \`void\*' to \`char\*' when using malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099669/invalid-conversion-from-void-to-char-when-using-malloc)

Comment: @LogicStuff I'm trying to avoid malloc here, not trying to use it, so sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Why use dynamic memory at all? Why not just `uv_loop_t loop; uv_loop_init(&loop);`?

Comment: In c++ you should be using `new`

Comment: @EdHeal well I should be using unique_ptr but I ain't sure if it won't explode my system. /jk i don't know how to use it.

Comment: In c++ it's imperatif to cast `void*` to the correct type using ``reinterpret_cast``. But while using C++ you can use ``new`` operator instead of ``malloc``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C a `void*`, the return type of `malloc`, converts implicitly to any other data pointer type.

In C++ it does not.

C also has implicit `int`, which means that best practice for use of `malloc` differs between the languages. In C the result should not be casted, because if one is missing an `#include` this could implicitly declare `malloc` with `int` result. In C++, however, the result must be casted if it's used as anything other than a `void*`.

Your code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <uv.h>

int main() {
    uv_loop_t *loop = malloc(sizeof(uv_loop_t));
    uv_loop_init(loop);

    std::cout << "Running loop" << std::endl;
    uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

    uv_loop_close(loop);
    free(loop);
    return 0;
}
```

… is better expressed as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <uv.h>

int main() {
    uv_loop_t loop;
    uv_loop_init(&loop);

    std::cout << "Running loop" << std::endl;
    uv_run(&loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

    uv_loop_close(&loop);
}
```