# Difference between linked list traversal **while(thead != NULL)** and while(thead->next !=NULL)

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between **while(thead != NULL)** and **while(thead->next !=NULL)** because for traversing the list **thead != NULL** is not working while **thead->next** works. 
According to my understanding head node is just a pointer to the starting node and not the the starting node itself.
[See this if u have doubt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oRQD.png).Here head just stores address.

//thead means temp head variable to store the address head points to.
This is the code for insertion.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *head;
void insert(int x)
{
    struct node *temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));   
    temp->data=x;   
    temp->next=NULL;   
    if(head==NULL)     
    {     
         head=temp;    
    }
    else
    {
        struct node * thead;
        thead=head;  
        while(thead->next!=NULL)
        {
            thead=thead->next;  
        }
        thead->next=temp;
    }
}

void print()
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {

        printf("%d",temp->data);
            temp=temp->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    head=NULL;
    int i,n,x;
    printf("enter number of nodes");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("enter no");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        insert(x);
    }
    print();
}
```

**If we replace thead ->next != NULL by thead !=NULL then dev c++ stops working.Vice versa happens in the printf for traversal ...**

So can someone answer the difference between the above two?

Also,Is head node the first node which contains both data and address or does it just stores addresses like in the diagram above?

Also if the head node is only a pointer which stores address then how are we able access thead->next ?

And when is a pointer to a structure NULL?

Thanks

Comment: just added the whole code

Comment: Try to answer for yourself following questions. What `thead==NULL` condition means in this scope? What `thead->next==NULL` condition means in this scope?

Comment: If thread equals NULL then thread->next = temp tries to dereference a NULL pointer.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Is the condition you have mentioned possible in this algorithm?

Comment: If code uses `while(thead != NULL) { ... }`, than after the loop, what should get set to `temp`?   What needs to get set to `temp` is some `.next` member, but of what pointer?

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski, if u saw the diagram  can u answer the 3rd and last question at the end?

Comment: @chux cud u elaborate ?

Comment: A key difference between `insert()` and `print()` is that the first alters the list, and the 2nd does not.   To alter the list, the node address needs to be remembered and not just the `.next` member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `print()`, code does not need to remember the last node address after the loop

```
temp=head;
while(temp!=NULL) {
    printf("%d",temp->data);
    temp=temp->next;
}
// temp == NULL at this point and code does not care what the last node was.
```

With `insert()`, code does need to remember the last node address after the loop.

```
// First handle special case where the head of the list is NULL
// otherwise ....
while(thead->next!=NULL) {
    thead = thead->next;  
}
// temp->next == NULL at this point
// Code can use `thead` to access the last node's members.
thead->next = temp;
```

---

> Is head node the first node which contains both data and address or does it just stores addresses like in the diagram above?

`struct node *head` is a pointer.  When `head != NULL`, it pointer the the frist node which contains data and a next pointer.

> if the head node is only a pointer which stores address then how are we able access thead->next ?

`thead` is initialized with `head`.  By de-referencing `thead`, code has access to that node's members including `.next`.

> when is a pointer to a structure NULL?

Question is unclear.  A pointer to a `struct` is `NULL` when it has a value equal to `NULL`.  This is usually as the end in the linked-list code employs.

Comment: can u answer the last 3 questions so i can have some more clarity ?

Comment: @Shaurya Why did you code `struct node *temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` instead of a more simple `struct node *temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));` or even better `struct node *temp =
 malloc(sizeof *temp);`?  The last being preferred.

Comment: malloc returns a void pointer meaning memory has been allocated but not associated with any data type. So actually here i am doing type casting to user generated data type which is (struct node*).

Comment: @Shaurya C does not need the cast to work - it is unnnessary.  Use `struct node *temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` if [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).  Use `struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);` if [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: [Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'node*' [-fpermissive] Implementing what u suggest gives this error in dev c++.

Comment: This post is C and my comments apply to C.  You are compiling using a different language:  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5099675/2410359).  Use a C compiler for C code.

Answer (score 1):

Now since I have actually understood....for those who are still stuck I am writing this....

When I use (thead!=NULL) the thead pointer actually points to each and every element in the list.When it reaches the last element,it still traverses to the next element which is NULL unlike (thead->next!=NULL) which stops at the last element of the linked list.

In case of print we need to print all the values in the list so we use while(thead!=NULL) as we need to print the last element too.For traversing we simply need to make the pointer point towards the last node so we can stop at it and not traverse till we reach the NULL pointer.

We cant dereference NULL and so there was an error.