# How to explain this doubly linked list code?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Is the explanation of this piece of code about Doubly Linked List correct?

I cannot understand a part of the code. What's happening in this piece of code?

I have explained parts of code, but not very sure if it's correct or not.

```
void DoublyLinkedList::SortedInsert(const int& new_element) {


    if (new_element != 0) {                      //creates new node np with value equal to new element
        Node* np = new Node(new_element); //if new element is not equal to zero and if its not head, it points to both                                              
                                                         head and  tail
        if (!Head)
        {
            Head = np;
            Tail = np;


        }
        else if (new_element < Head->Element)   //if new element less than element in Head np's  next pointer pointing to                                        
                                                        Head and Head prev pointer pointing to np and Head is pointing to np
        {
            np->Next = Head;
            Head->Prev = np;
            Head = np;


        }
        else                                     //if new element is greater than Head we take cur node which is pointing                                      
                                                   to Head's next pointer pointing to node after Head
        {

            Node *cur = Head->Next;
            while ((cur) && (new_element >= cur->Element))  //new element greater than Node after Head,cur will point to                                            cur's next pointer which is node after cur
                cur = cur->Next;

            if (cur)
            {                                            // ?? whats happening here
                np->Prev = cur->Prev;
                np->Next = cur;
                cur->Prev->Next = np;
                cur->Prev = np;
            }
            else                                         // ?? whats happening here
            {
                Tail->Next = np;
                np->Prev = Tail;
                Tail = np;
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: I highly recommend using pen and paper and drawing the list as you walk through the code.  Use arrows to point to nodes.  The operations will become more clear.  IMHO, always draw with linked lists & trees.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews I did use drawing in paper but its getting very confusing...Can you please help in understanding parts of code?

Comment: if you dont understand the last part tell me , i will answer tmrw

Comment: also, you can have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530609/difference-between-linked-list-traversal-whilethead-null-and-whilethea ....even i was struggling once it will make you better understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed where it seems something is wrong.
Remember in dll, there will be 2 pointers one pointing to next and other to previous element. Each element of dll has data, *next and  *prev.

void DoublyLinkedList::SortedInsert(const int& new_element) {

```
    if (new_element != 0) {                      //creates new node np with value equal to new element
        Node* np = new Node(new_element); 

       //Here we create just a pointer of type 'node' if new element is not 
       //equal to zero and if no head exists then obviously this is the 1st 
       //element, hence head and tail  points to both 1st element.                                  
        if (!Head)
        {
            Head = np;
            Tail = np;
        }

        //if new element less than element in Head np's  next pointer 
        //pointing to Head and Head prev pointer pointing to np and Head is  
        //pointing to np

        //Here it seems you are thinking wrong. Remember head never has next 
        //or previous pointer. It always points to first element unless we 
        //make it move. You mentioned Head np's next pointer, that will be 
        //Head->element->next and not head->element. Head->element means the 
        //first position and if our list already has a element to which head
        //is pointing we compare it with our new element which we want to 
        //insert. 

        else if (new_element < Head->Element)                                                                               
        {                                 //if new elm is less than 1st elm
            np->Next = Head;              //now new elm bcms 1st elm as it next pointer points to the one is currently being pointed by head
            Head->Prev = np;              //now elm pointed by head prev pointer will point to new element
            Head = np;                    //finally our new element is 1st //element in list hence we assigb head pointer to point towards it.    


        }
        //this is the condition when new elmt which we are inserting is 
        //greater than our element pointed by head. Thus obviously  
        //we need to traverse and find the element which is greater than
        //our new element. This code does that and then adjusts the next and 
        //previous pointer
        else                                     
        {

            Node *cur = Head->Next;
            while ((cur) && (new_element >= cur->Element))  
                cur = cur->Next;

            if (cur)
            {                                           
                np->Prev = cur->Prev;
                np->Next = cur;
                cur->Prev->Next = np;
                cur->Prev = np;
            }
            else                                       
            {
                Tail->Next = np;
                np->Prev = Tail;
                Tail = np;
            }
        }


    }
```

Hope it helps !