# It must be an expression whose only persistent side effect is to modify the loop counter

Tags: c, for-loop, misra

```
//non-compliant code according to misra-c:
for (istate_list = e_spat->intersections; istate_list != NULL; istate_list = istate_list->next, i++)
```

What is wrong here? If someone explain about the above that would be great.

Comment: It's more usual to use `while` for a linked list.

Comment: About the voting to close: what was the exact complete error message?

Comment: @ryyker How is `istate_list = istate_list->next` not related to the first and second expressions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530609/difference-between-linked-list-traversal-whilethead-null-and-whilethea

Comment: @user1234 I don't think that's a dup. It does not mention MISRA but seeems to be more about deferencing a possibly NULL pointer, which the posted code here does not do.

Comment: the 3rd part is also modifying `i`

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. This isn't related to the compiler but the static analyser (MISRA checker). Sure, it's helpful to know which version of MISRA  and which tool that is used, but that info alone missing isn't really reason enough to close the question. It should be obvious to anyone knowing MISRA what the problem is. And anyone not knowing MISRA should refrain from moderating such questions... voting to re-open.

Comment: Anyway, in case this doesn't get re-opened, the reason is simply because you are spewing unrelated stuff into the 3 clauses of a for loop. Rule 14.2. This `istate_list = istate_list->next, i++` is 2 side effects in a single clause. You need to rewrite the loop to either use `i` as loop counter, or to only use `i` inside the for loop body. Or rewrite it as a `while`, that would work as well.

Comment: Thanks, @Lundin.  I thought that might have been it, but as someone not knowing MISRA, I refrained from speculating.  Out of curiosity: would `for(istate_list = intersections, i = 0; istate_list != NULL; istate_list = istate_list->next, i++)` also have been noncompliant?  I've written that more than once, and since it's the job of a `for` loop to centralize a loop's initialization, test, and increment steps, I consider this *good* style, although I can see how it might be a subtlety beyond the scope of a finitely complex set of guidelines. (But clearly `i` isn't "unrelated stuff" here.)

Comment: @SteveSummit Yeah code like that is common practice, but the intention of the MISRA rule is to keep the for loop as clean and readable as possible and the rationale is to ban far worse examples than yours (like `i --> n` and other such "fun" code). Clause 1 can only contain initialization/assignment of the loop counter (or be empty), clause 2 can only be an expression with no side effects and it needs to use the loop counter, clause 3 can only contain the side effect of updating the loop counter and may not use other objects modified in the loop body. `for(;;)` is also allowed.

Comment: `istate_list = intersections; for(uint32_t i=0u; (istate_list != NULL) && (i < max); i++)
{ ... istate_list = istate_list->next; }` should be a MISRA compliant re-write, far as I can tell.

Comment: @Lundin You say "the loop counter" as if there's inherently only one. I suppose that, everything else being equal, a loop with two parallel counters is unusual and potentially confusing.  But here we have a situation where if someone is bound and determined to write a loop with two counters, they are forbidden to write it in the clearest possible way (with relevant info for *both* counters centralized in the `for` loop header), but are rather forced to sprinkle the information for the non-primary counter around elsewhere, making it harder to find and verify.

Comment: But this isn't the place to debate what MISRA should or shouldn't say, so I'll try to avoid prolonging this side discussion any further.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yes, only one counter is allowed. I used to write loops with multiple counters using the comma operator as well, at some point. Though later decided that the form `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)` is such a canonical form that one shouldn't be messing with it. Thus I would personally say that `j=0; for(int i=0; i<n; i++) { ... j++; }` is more readable than `for(int i=0, j=0; i<n; i++, j++)`. Which is quite a subjective topic.

Comment: Related: there's also an advisory rule in MISRA C to avoid using the comma iterator in the first place. Which is quite sensible too, since using it can lead to precedence bugs, mix-ups with initializer/function parameter lists and so on. The main purpose of the comma iterator is to write function-like macros returning a value and well, function-like macros should also be avoided for MISRA compliance.

Comment: @SteveSummit - Yeah, that was a mis-statement.  I intended to point out that the ***"index `i`*** _in your loop's 3rd argument is not related in..."_.  Within the context of the  post, `i` plays no apparent role.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simply because you are mixing multiple unrelated expressions into the same clause of a `for` loop. Rule 14.2 is pretty clear regarding what's allowed and what isn't.

`istate_list = istate_list->next, i++` is 2 side effects in a single clause. And also the use of the comma operator which violates another MISRA rule.

You need to rewrite the loop to either use `i` as a proper loop counter, or to only use `i` inside the `for` loop body. Or rewrite it as a `while`, that would work as well.

One possible MISRA C-compliant example:

```
istate_list = intersections; 
for(uint32_t i=0u; i<max; i++) 
{ 
  // ... 
  istate_list = istate_list->next; 
  if (istate_list == NULL)
  {
    break;
  }
}
```