# it works fine without AddressSanitizer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

World! I am bad at dynamic memory allocation so please help me! The problem is that when i compile c file without sanitizer it executes normally.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        char *str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
        int i = 1;
        while (str[i - 2] != '\n')
        {
                str = (char *)realloc(str, i * sizeof(char));
                str[i - 1] = getchar();
                i++;
        }
        str[++i] = '\0';
        fputs(str, stdout);
        free(str);
        return 0;
}
```

here what sanitizer says:

```
==7174==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000000f at pc 0x55739456b340 bp 0x7fffba0090f0 sp 0x7fffba0090e0
READ of size 1 at 0x60200000000f thread T0
    #0 0x55739456b33f in main (/home/bek/diff1+0x133f)
    #1 0x7fd15ff780b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
    #2 0x55739456b1ad in _start (/home/bek/diff1+0x11ad)

0x60200000000f is located 1 bytes to the left of 1-byte region [0x602000000010,0x602000000011)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7fd160250bc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
    #1 0x55739456b27e in main (/home/bek/diff1+0x127e)
    #2 0x7fd15ff780b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow (/home/bek/diff1+0x133f) in main
```

Comment: Always reallocating one more byte for the buffer seems rather inefficient. You might want to reconsider that approach first.

Comment: You might want something like `char c = getchar(); if(c == '\n') break;` to avoid the problematic if statement that @SouravGhosh found.

Comment: @AKX [**`int c`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35356684/918959) :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Sure, forgot about <del>Dre</del> EOF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem in

```
 while (str[i - 2] != '\n')
```

for the very first iteration, `i` is `1`, so the index value is `-1`, which is an invalid index.

That said, couple of more important things:

- Memory returned by `malloc()` is uninitialised. If you try to read it before you assign any value to the memory, you'll be hit with indeterminate value and the program behaviour is not predictable.
- The syntax

  ```
  str = (char *)realloc(str, i * sizeof(char));
  ```

  is a very problematic one, in case `realloc()` fails and returns a `NULL`, you'll end up losing the original pointer, too!

  Always check for success of the `realloc()` call before assigning the returned value to the variable, something like

  ```
  char * tmp = NULL;
  tmp = realloc(str, i);  // cast not needed, sizeof(char) == 1 in C
  if (!tmp) { exit(1); /* or cleanup*/}
  str = tmp;              // assign otherwise
  ```
- [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a POSIX system, just use the wheel instead of reinventing it:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *str = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    ssize_t result = getline(&str, &n, stdin);

    if (result < 0) {
        perror("An error occurred in getline");
        exit(1);
    }

    fputs(str, stdout);
    free(str);
}
```

Should you ever need to venture to the lesser systems, there are many implementations for standard `getline` using just standard C library facilities.

Comment: Huh, if the Musl implementation of getline/getdelim is this... non-straightforward (touching the internals of `FILE*`s?), I dare not look at how glibc does it. https://github.com/BlankOn/musl/blob/0ffdbf9909fc26f1418c04d971f11900da9401dc/src/stdio/getdelim.c

Comment: @AKX that's because getchar etc will need to have locking. There is a QA on that.

Comment: @AKX https://stackoverflow.com/a/47229318/918959 :P

Comment: @AKX also related straight from the horse's mouth: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167946/how-do-i-read-an-arbitrarily-long-line-in-c/12169132#comment16288791_12169132