# Removing neighboring duplicate lines from a file using C

Tags: c, duplicates, lines

Empty lines also should be removed if they are duplicates. If line has escape sequences (like `\t`), it's different than empty line. Code below is deleting too many lines, or sometimes leave duplicates. How to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char a[6000];
    char b[6000];
    int test = 0;
    fgets(a, 6000, stdin);
    while (fgets(b, 6000, stdin) != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6000; i++) {
            if (a[i] != b[i]) {
                test = 1;
            }
        }
        if (test == 0) {
            fgets(b, 6000, stdin);
        } else {
            printf("%s", a);
        }
        int j = 0;
        while (j < 6000) {
            a[j] = b[j];
            j++;
        }
        test = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the input of either of the lines is less than 5999 characters (including newline), then part of your arrays will be uninitialized and will have *indeterminate* contents.

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: Lots of issues here. The string comparison tests all 6000 bytes of `a` and `b`, even if they actually contain strings that are much shorter. You aren't stripping the newline characters from the end of each input line, so if the file ends on two identical lines without a final newline character, then both  lines will be left behind. Your program will also fail if any line is longer than 5999 characters.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage a line without newline is different from a line with newline! A line without newline isn't even valid in POSIX (a line in text file is *terminated* by `\n`)

Comment: Also, instead of `6000`, if this is POSIX system I'd just use `LINE_MAX` from [`<limits.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html) instead of the magic number.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Well, OK. But that's not how [`uniq`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniq) behaves.

Comment: `fgets()` guarantees that it will zero terminate the string it reads, so you can use `strcmp()` or `strncmp()` or (if you wish) do comparisons by hand that check for the terminator - that will avoid undefined behaviour that results from checking all characters in the buffer.   You also need to allow for the possibility of a line in the file longer than the buffer length - which `fgets()` does handle, but you need to check for it.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage that is true.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is mostly sound. You are on the right track with your train of thought:

1. Read a line into `previous` (`a`).
2. Read another line into `current` (`b`).
3. If `previous` and `current` have the same contents, go to step 2.
4. Print `previous`.
5. Move `current` to `previous`.
6. Go to step 2.

This still has some problems, however.

---

### Unnecessary line-read

To start, consider this bit of code:

```
while(fgets(b,6000,stdin)!=NULL) {
    ...
    if(test==0) {
        fgets(b,6000,stdin);
    }
    else {
        printf("%s",a);
    }
    ...
}
```

If `a` and `b` have the same contents (`test==0`), you use an unchecked `fgets` to read a line again, except you read **again** when the loop condition `fgets(b,6000,stdin)!=NULL` is evaluated. The problem is that you're mostly ignoring the line you just read, meaning you're moving an unknown line from `b` to `a`. Since the loop already reads another line and checks for failure appropriately, just let the loop read the line, and invert the `if` statement's equality test to print `a` if `test!=0`.

---

### Where's the last line?

Your logic also will not print the last line. Consider a file with 1 line. You read it, then `fgets` in the loop condition attempts to read another line, which fails because you're at the end of the file. There is no print statement outside the loop, so you never print the line.

Now what about a file with 2 lines that differ? You read the first line, then the last line, see they're different, and print the first line. Then you overwrite the first line's buffer with the last line. You fail to read another line because there aren't any more, and the last line is, again, not printed.

You can fix this by replacing the first (unchecked) `fgets` with `a[0] = 0`. That makes the first byte of `a` a null byte, which means the end of the string. It won't compare equal to a line you read, so `test==1`, meaning `a` will be printed. Since there is no string in `a` to print, nothing is printed.  Things then continue as normal, with the contents of `b` being moved into `a` and another line being read.

---

### Unique last line problem

This leaves one problem: the last line won't be printed if it's not a duplicate. To fix this, just print `b` instead of `a`.

---

### The final recipe

1. Assign `0` to the first byte of `previous` (`a[0]`).
2. Read a line into `current` (`b`).
3. If `previous` and `current` have the same contents, go to step 2.
4. Print `current`.
5. Move `current` to `previous`.
6. Go to step 2.

As you can see, it's not much different from your existing logic; only steps 1 and 4 differ. It also ensures that all `fgets` calls are checked. If there are no lines in a file, nothing is printed. If there is only 1 line in a file, it is printed. If 2 lines differ, both are printed. If 2 lines are the same, the first is printed.

---

### Optional: optimizations

- Instead of checking all 6000 bytes, you only check up to the first null byte in either string since `fgets` will automatically add one to mark the end of the string.
- Faster still would be to add a `break` statement inside the `if` statement of your `for` loop. If a single byte doesn't match, the entire line is not a duplicate, so you can stop comparing early—a lot faster if only byte 10 differs in two 1000-byte lines!

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
char buff[2][6000];
unsigned count=0;
char *prev=NULL
        , *this= buff[count%2]
        ;
while( fgets(this, sizeof buff[0] , stdin)) {
        if(!prev || strcmp(prev, this) ) { // first or different
                fputs(this, stdout);
                prev=this;
                count++;
                this=buff[count%2];
                }
        }
fprintf(stderr, "Number of lines witten: %u\n", count);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your code, like :

```
    for(int i=0; i<6000; i++) {
        if(a[i]!=b[i]) {
            test=1;
        }
    }
```

In this loop, every time the whole buffer will be compared character by character even if it finds `if(a[i]!=b[i])` for some value of `i`. Probably you should break loop after `test=1`.

Your logic will also not work for a file with just 1 line as you are not printing line outside the loop.

Another problem is fixed length buffer of size of 6000 char.

May you can use `getline` to solve your problem. You can do -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        char * line = NULL;
        char * comparewith = NULL;
        int notduplicate;
        size_t len = 0;
        ssize_t read;

        while ((read = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1) {
                ((comparewith == NULL ) || (strcmp (line, comparewith) != 0)) ? (notduplicate = 1) : (notduplicate = 0);
                if (notduplicate) {
                        printf ("%s\n", line);
                        if (comparewith != NULL)
                                free(comparewith);
                        comparewith = line;
                        line = NULL;
                }
        }

        if (line)
                free (line);

        if (comparewith)
                free (comparewith);

        return 0;
}
```

**An important point to note:**

`getline()` is not in the C standard library. `getline()` was originally GNU extension and [standardized in POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html). So, this code may not be portable. To make it portable, you'll need to roll your own `getline()` something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735126/are-there-alternate-implementations-of-gnu-getline-interface/735472#735472).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler solution that has no limitation on line length:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c, last1 = 0, last2 = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != '\n' || last1 != '\n' || last2 != '\n')
            putchar(c);
        last2 = last1;
        last1 = c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code skips sequences of more than 2 consecutive newline characters, hence it removes duplicate blank lines.